# True Hamiltonian in Geometrodynamics

Tags: general-relativity, hamiltonian-formalism, quantum-gravity, constrained-dynamics, gauge

If I set $N=1$ and $N^a=0$ in the Einstein-Hilbert action $$S[N,N^a,q_{ab}]=\int\sqrt{\mathrm{det}(g)}\,R\,\mathrm d^4x \,\text{,}$$ expressed in terms of ADM variables, then $N$ and $N^a$ are no longer configuration variables for this gauge fixed system anymore. Consequently, I don't need to compute their conjuage momenta when going to the Hamiltonian formalism. Since these conjuagte momenta would normally become the primary constraints, I don't get primary constraints anymore and consequently no secondary constraints either. Hence, I get a true Hamiltonian instead of the hypersurface deformation constraint algebra. My intuition is that this should then be much easier to quantize.

Unfortunately, I was told that this has already been done. My questions are:

1. What did people try exactly and what problems did they run into?
2. It seems to be generally preferred to use deparametrized systems instead. Why?

Comment: I don't understand why the quantum-gravity tag was removed, because this is what I'm mostly interested in. The classical part seems pretty clear unless I misunderstood something.

Comment: I can give you another literature: http://www.blau.itp.unibe.ch/newlecturesGR.pdf. Look at  page 806- 813. This should answer the question